# Measuring build times to identify bottlenecks

Tags: optimization, makefile, build-process

I'm working on improving the build for a few projects.  I've improved build times quite significantly, and I'm at a point now where I think the bottlenecks are more subtle.

The build uses GNU style makefiles.  I generate a series of dependency files (`.d`) and include them in the makefile, otherwise there's nothing fancy going on (eg, no pre-compiled headers or other caching mechanisms).

The build takes about 95 seconds on a 32-core sparc ultra, running with 16 threads in parallel.  Idle time hovers around 80% while the build runs, with kernel time hovering between 8-10%.  I put the code in /tmp, but most of the compiler support files are NFS mounted and I believe this may be creating a performance bottleneck.

What tools exist for measuring & tracking down these sorts of problems?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using precompiled headers? In my experience those can DRAMATICALLY speedup the whole process.

Comment: For me, linking takes about 2 min. by itself. Full compiling can take over 5+ min. When I do full optimization builds, all the modules get merged into one to allow for full IPO. I typically run like 5 - 10 of these builds simultaneously for different architectures. (which is the only to get multicore compile since the modules are merged.)

Comment: @Voo - It's on the docket, I just haven't gone down that path yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, compiling C/C++ code requires reading a lot of header files by C preprocessor. I've experienced situations when it took more than 50% of g++ run-time to generate a complete translation unit.

As you mentioned that it idles 80% when compiling it must be waiting for I/O then. `iostat` and DTrace would be a good starting point.